# MSMQ.MSMQApplication BytesInAllQueues shows large number where no messages visible in queues

Tags: msmq

I have a vbs script [1] that tidies up MSMQ and it's showing that I have ~1GB in all queues. However, using GUI tools and some PShell scripting [2] I see no queue messages.

How do I truly purge these queues?

[1]

```
Option Explicit

Dim mqa
set mqa = WScript.CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQApplication")

WScript.Echo "Bytes in all queues: " + CStr(mqa.BytesInAllQueues)

mqa.Tidy

WScript.Echo "MSMQ cleaned up"
```

[2]

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".") | % { if($_.GetAllMessages().Length -gt 0) { $_.QueueName + $_.GetAllMessages().Length } $_.Purge(); }
```

Comment: I found what appears to have been the culprit in the System Queues. However, after purging these messages, I still see quite a bit in the BytesInAllQueues.

Comment: Could be Journal messages.